# runtime vector<int> STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: c++, vector, qsort

I have a vector< int> having the inorder traversal of a binary tree. Now I sort it using qsort. After that when I tried to print the contents of the vector, following error occurred at runtime.

```
[main] C:\General_algorithms\binaryTreeToBST.exe 1000 (0) handle_exceptions
: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
[main] binaryTreeToBST 1000 (0) handle_exceptions: Dumping stack trace to binary
TreeToBST.exe.core
```

The code is given below:

```
struct BinTreeNode
{
    int id;
    BinTreeNode *left;
    BinTreeNode *right;

    BinTreeNode(int a)
    {
        id=a;
        left=right=NULL;
    }
};

int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main()
{
    BinTreeNode n10(10);
    BinTreeNode n2(2);
    BinTreeNode n7(7);
    BinTreeNode n8(8);
    BinTreeNode n4(4);
    n10.left=&n2;
    n10.right=&n7;
    n2.left= &n8;
    n2.right= &n4;

    cout<<"OK TILL HERE1"<<endl;
    vector<int> InTr= inorder(n10); //returns a vector containing the inorder traversal of the tree.
    cout<<"OK TILL HERE2"<<endl;

    if(InTr.size()!=0)
    qsort(&InTr, InTr.size(), InTr[0], compare);
    cout<<"OK TILL HERE3"<<endl; //THIS GETS PRINTED

    cout<<InTr[0];  //THIS DOESN'T GET PRINTED(Error occurs)
    for(int i=0;i<InTr.size();i++)
        cout<<InTr[i]<<endl;
         cout<<"OK TILL HERE4"<<endl; //THIS DOESN'T GET PRINTED
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `qsort(&InTr, InTr.size(), InTr[0], compare);` that doesn't look right. Third argument should be `sizeof(int)`. Why not use `std::sort(InTr.begin(), InTr.end())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to do this, but I guess this may fix the problem

`qsort(&InTr[0], InTr.size(), sizeof(int), compare);`

Instead use algorithm's [`sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort). qsort is slower

Answer (score 2):

```
&InTr
```

- is an address of vector object, not tha actual data. It should be:

```
InTr.data() or &InTr[0]
```

And the 3rd argument should be:

```
sizeof(InTr[0]),
```

like greatwolf said.

BTW, consider using sort from STL, it's more "C++'ish".

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is coming from your use of:

```
qsort(&InTr, InTr.size(), InTr[0], compare);
```

The third argument expects the size of the element being sorted. Passing in `InTr[0]` is clearly wrong here since it can contain any value for `int` which likely won't equal `sizeof(vector<int>::value_type)`.

The use of `&InTr` as the first parameter is also wrong since elements in `std::vector`'s  doesn't have to start at its base address. By passing in vector like that you effectively let `qsort` clobber vector's internal state. At this point, trying to use vector becomes unpredictable. Luckily in your case, you got an access violation.

The other answers already mention the preferred approach so I won't restate it here.